# Connecting AWS DMS to Redshift Serverless?

Tags: aws-dms, amazon-redshift-serverless

I've tried using the workgroup endpoint, and Redshift-managed VPC endpoints, but get the error message:

> Cluster 'XXXXX' does not exist.

Does that seem like a VPC issue, or is there a quirk re Redshift Serverless?  Anyone using this combo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what it seems DMS doesn't support Redshift serverless yet:
https://repost.aws/questions/QUxMagDflyR1O9TpjLE7fjxg/how-to-create-dms-migration-endpoint-for-redshift-serverless

Comment: For others, I've been told (but haven't tried) that you can add it as long as you do it via cli instead of the gui.

Comment: @MikeKarp For others, thanks but I've just tried it and got the same error as in the web console - "An error occurred (InvalidResourceStateFault) when calling the CreateEndpoint operation: Cluster 'default' does not exist." - where 'default' is the workgroup & namespace name, at the front of the `ServerName` (hostname).